# level must be an integer, error in elasticsearch

Tags: python, selenium, elasticsearch, web-scraping, scrapy

I have implemented a little crawler in python and I wanted to try to export the results in elasticsearch as explained in this [tutorial](http://blog.florian-hopf.de/2014/07/scrapy-and-elasticsearch.html).

I've made the fix proposed in the comment because of the update of the elasticsearch for scrapy plug-in (cf [github link](https://github.com/knockrentals/scrapy-elasticsearch)). I've changed the ELASTICSEARCH_UNIQ_KEY with an existing field in my scraper. Of course I have installed the plugin and checked that my spider worked (I have succeeded in getting output in json the command `scrapy crawl brand -o output.json` where brand is the name of my spider)

I've installed elasticsearch and it is running, I have been able to reproduce some examples found [here](http://blog.zenika.com/index.php?post/2012/11/14/Premiers-pas-avec-ElasticSearch-Partie-1). But it doesn't work when I'm using the following command :`scrapy crawl brand`.

I added quotes in the line `ELASTICSEARCH_LOG_LEVEL= 'log.DEBUG'` in the settings.py file since log is not recognized without. But now, I have the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stephanie\Downloads\WinPython-32bit-2.7.9.2\python-2.7.9\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\stephanie\Downloads\WinPython-32bit-2.7.9.2\python-2.7.9\lib\site-packages\scrapyelasticsearch\scrapyelasticsearch.py", line 70, in process_item
    self.index_item(item)
  File "C:\Users\stephanie\Downloads\WinPython-32bit-2.7.9.2\python-2.7.9\lib\site-packages\scrapyelasticsearch\scrapyelasticsearch.py", line 53, in index_item
    log.msg("Generated unique key %s" % local_id, level=self.settings.get('ELASTICSEARCH_LOG_LEVEL'))
  File "C:\Users\stephanie\Downloads\WinPython-32bit-2.7.9.2\python-2.7.9\lib\site-packages\scrapy\log.py", line 49, in msg
    logger.log(level, message, *[kw] if kw else [])
  File "C:\Users\stephanie\Downloads\WinPython-32bit-2.7.9.2\python-2.7.9\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1220, in log
    raise TypeError("level must be an integer")
TypeError: level must be an integer
2015-08-04 02:06:02 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 1 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-08-04 02:06:02 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-08-04 02:06:02 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: DELETE
http://127.0.0.1:49654/hub/session/209677e4-1577-4f05-a418-8554159d8c74/window {
"sessionId": "209677e4-1577-4f05-a418-8554159d8c74"}
2015-08-04 02:06:03 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2015-08-04 02:06:03 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

I am using python 2.7 and elasticsearch 1.7.1
Do I have to do some configuration with elastic search or what may cause this error ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have an ElasticSearch setup to try this on, but you could try modifying settings.py, add the following to the top of settings.py

```
import logging
```

And change

```
ELASTICSEARCH_LOG_LEVEL= 'log.DEBUG'
```

to

```
ELASTICSEARCH_LOG_LEVEL= logging.DEBUG
```

If the above still doesn't work, you can try this instead:

```
ELASTICSEARCH_LOG_LEVEL= 10
```

Comment: Your first solution works ! Awsome ! Thank you very much

Comment: No worries.  My pleasure.